# Jquery plugin DataTables, custom filtering

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I set a custom filter in my code to ignore accents and special character from the table before filtering?

I am using DataTables plugin (http://www.datatables.net/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include a version of the data that is missing the accents as a column in the datatable. You hide that column by adding an entry in the `aoColumns` array in the configuration literal.

Let's say you start with 4 columns. One of these has accents. Add a fifth column with non-accented data, and add a configuration literal with `{ "bVisible": false }` so that it will not be displayed.

It's invisible, but it's still searchable / filterable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [ 
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "bVisible": false }
        ] } );
});
```

See the [column documentation](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) for more on configuration. **[DataTables with hidden columns](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html)** is an example in use.

Comment: Using this, I have to set the number of columns manualy, right? 
Doesn't exists a way to hide a column without especify the number of columns?

Comment: Right, each of those `null`'s represents no extra configuration. In my experience with using ajax and DataTables, the number of columns needs to match the number of entries in `aoColumns`